# How to echo variables randomized

Tags: php, scramble

I'm learning php on a very basic level and need som assistance.

I want to echo variables from one file to another. I'll try to reproduce:

folder/file1.php
file1.php contains 3 different php scripts:

```
php $var1 = "Hello"
php $var2 = "Goodbye"
php $var3 = "Nice"
```

And i want to echo one of the three variables randomly (scrambled) on various pages.

I use this now:

```
php include 'folder/file1.php'; echo get_($var1);
```

But it only displays the $var1 text.

Comment: If you print `$var1` it prints the value of `$var1`. Why wouldn't it?

Comment: what is `php` doing before `$var` ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
<?php

$var1 = "Hello";
$var2 = "Goodbye";
$var3 = "Nice";

$i = rand(1, 3);
echo ${"var" . $i}

?>
```

At run time `${"var" . $i}` is calculated to be `$var1`, `$var2` or `$var3`.

Using php [rand](https://www.php.net/rand) and dynamically created variable will let you do it. You can just continue to include your other files above this script and ensure the variables are named in a static way as shown above and it will work.

Example: [Here](http://ideone.com/k3vvGI) (click edit then ideoneit)

Comment: Beautiful! This worked with a slight modification to read from "file to file" :-)

Comment: Glad I could help :) Don't forget to mark it as the answer if it is ;)

Answer (score 0):

put those vars in an array, and randomly select an element from the array:

```
$myItems = array("hello","goodbye","lovely");
echo $myItems[rand(0,2)];
```

https://www.php.net/rand

Comment: you are not answering the question, you are changing the question